# Is it possible to monitor LXTerminal(shell) outputs in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have just recently started to learn Perl so please excuse my lack of technical vocabulary when it comes to this language.

I have a Perl script that uses mpg321 to play audio. I  have the command:

```
if(song is not being played)
{
     system("mpg321 song.mp3 &");
}
```

I wanted to know if it was possible to check if there is a song already being played.
mpg321 outputs to the terminal once done playing a song. My train of thought led me to believe if I could "monitor" the terminal for the output:

[0:00] Decoding of song.mp3 finished

I can put that into the if statement somehow. If there is an easier way to do this or if this method I mentioned is possible I would be greatly appreciative of the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can open execution pipe and watch for output from that pipe, something like:

```
my $pipe;
open $pipe, "mpg321 song.mp3 |";
while (my $line = <$pipe> {
    # check if mpg321 printed something...
}
```

But this would only work if you can convince `mpg321` to disable console buffering.